# Realizar una sumatoria y guardar en variable de session ? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

estoy usando variables de session para guardar los datos y la tabla, usuarios,etc (Luego viajan a otra pagina) y pues tengo el dilema que no puedo resolver que pasos a seguir requiero para hacer la sumatoria del label Total. Soy practicamente nuevo con c# asp.net y no se mucho de la codificación. Gracias por cualquier ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo que uso en la session de la tabla si se pudiera integrar (quizás tomar el dato de la celda cantidad mientras de vaya creando y multiplicar , aunque nose que codigo iria en tal caso?)

```
if(Session["Dt"] == null)
    {
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable(); 
        Dt.Columns.Add("Sandwich");
        Dt.Columns.Add("Agregado");
        Dt.Columns.Add("Cantidad");

        Dt.Rows.Add(lista_sandwich.SelectedItem.Text, lista_agregado.SelectedItem.Text, caja_cantidad.Text); //Toma los campos del sandwich/agregado/cantidad (sus nombres y los une al row)
        tablita.DataSource = Dt;
        tablita.DataBind();
        Session["Dt"] = Dt;

        Session["cantidad"] = caja_cantidad.Text;
        label_suma.Text = Session["cantidad"].ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        DataTable Dt = Session["Dt"] as DataTable;
        Dt.Rows.Add(lista_sandwich.SelectedItem.Text, lista_agregado.SelectedItem.Text, caja_cantidad.Text); //Toma los campos del sandwich/agregado/cantidad (sus nombres y los une al row)
        tablita.DataSource = Dt;
        tablita.DataBind();
        Session["Dt"] = Dt;
```

Comment: como diferencias la cantidad de agregado y la de sandwich ?

Comment: Basicamente es la cantidad de sandwich(con un agregado) ya que no vendria con la opcion de no agregar.

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular el total podrias hacer algo como esto

```
int suma = 0;
foreach(var row in Dt){
  int cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(row["cantidad"]);
  suma += (cantidad  * 800) + (cantidad  * 200);
}

lblTotal.Text = suma.ToString();
```

Iteras cada row del datatable para realizar la suma, la otra forma seria usando linq

```
int suma = Dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r=> (r.Field<int>("cantidad") * 800) + (r.Field<int>("cantidad") * 200))
lblTotal.Text = suma.ToString();
```

[Consultas en LINQ to DataSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/queries-in-linq-to-dataset)

esta claro que linq reduce el codigo

Comment: El foreach me arroja que "Dt no puede funcionar en variables de datatable porque no contiene una definicion publica para GetEnumerator" :/ ¿Que significa?

Comment: valida que tengas la referencia a System.Data.DataSetExtensions. Sino prueba de reemplazar. Sino reemplaza el  AsEnumerable() por Dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()